# Get all the properties on a running Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, properties

I have a running Kafka cluster. How can I get all the properties of the running cluster?

I am looking to see the list of properties that is printed out when you first start the cluster.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the startup logs and having direct access to the `server.properties` file, those properties aren't exposed anywhere, to my knowledge, at least not with any built-in Kafka tooling.

If you're maintaining your own cluster, using configuration management tools in source control would be a place to maintain modified configurations, otherwise, you can refer the documentation for the defaults.